# Extract attributes from line to point shp

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap

If anyone can help me it would be great. I am using ArcMap 10 and would like to extract the attributes from a line shp (Roads) to a point shp created from the line shp. The points fall on the intersections and in the mid point of the roads. I would like to populate the point attributes table with that of the roads attributes? Is there an easy way to do this as i have over a 100 000 records? For example a point at the intersection i would like to create a field (Road names) of the two roads intersecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you need to use a [spatial join](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000q000000) to extract those values.

The main issue is that you want more than one attribute value when it comes to an intersection. If your points are already located at the intersection, you'll need to use the "ONE_TO_MANY" option. After the join, you will end up with duplicate points: summarize the table with "first" and "last" values of your fields, concatenate these two field (in the field calculator, !field_first! + !field_last!) and join back to your original point feature. However, BE CAREFUL, because this will only take two road names (you might have more at some intersections)

As a remark, if you have ArcInfo lincence you can also use the near tool.

Answer (score 0):

To create a Intersection list I first needed to Unsplit the lines with the Unsplit line tool. When this was completed I used the intersect tool. THis created points at the intersection. Delete duplicates tool was run to shape. Then I did a Spatial Join as suggested Radouxju.